# Why has a-word-to-describe-a-lot-of-people-who-lie-on-a-place been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why has [Describing a group of people who lie down in a public place to send a political message](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187104/a-word-to-describe-a-lot-of-people-who-lie-on-a-place) been closed?

I ask because the standard message written in the box is not sufficient to understand the why, neither It is clear what I should do to improve that question.

Comment: There is no word for it in English nor in any other language of my acquaintance. Such futile and nonproductive requests are just as off-topic here as they are on any other SE site.  We expect honest questions asked in good faith — not ones like yours.

Comment: @tchrist Strange, Kristina Lopez found a reference which says that that word exisists and it is 'die-in', .

Comment: Posting pictures of something that you cannot even be bothered to figure out the name of in your own language and then demanding that we make up names for them in English is **Not Constructive**.

Comment: This does indeed appear to be a good old-fashioned die-in. It's a legitimate question about a real thing with a real name, and it should be reopened (and as of a few minutes ago, it has been).

Comment: @tchrist: posting a picture of something you don't know the name of is, hands down, the absolute **best** way to ask such a question. What if the OP didn't know any language other than English? Would you still have considered the question "not constructive"?

Comment: @Marthaª If it were a picture of a stand of trees with a fence in front and a building in the background and the question were "What do you call this?" then yes, absolutely.

Comment: @KitFox: that's a straw man if I ever saw one.

Comment: @Marthaª Hahaha. Could be. Might could be a pumpkin patch. Can't hardly tell without context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think KitFox did a fine job of answering your direct question, so I won't bother with that bit.

I think your question could be improved with a paragraph explaining the context of the photo.  Perhaps you could talk about what you experienced in the 15 seconds leading up to the taking of the photo.

--

I was walking through the square, and I came upon a group of people all lying on the ground.  Each had a print out on their chest with a political message, and nobody was moving.

{photo>

What word or phrase could best be used to describe a group of people who lie down in a public place in order to send a political message?

--

The title could be improved in a similar manner.

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it is possible to reopen a question that has been closed, if the question is no longer seen as deficient.

Comment: It is possible to reopen questions, and I think you have given a good example of some improvements that could be made to the post, particularly, that it should have context.

Answer (score 9):

> Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase **must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests.](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

(emphasis mine)

You don't include information on how it will be used. Please also refer to the linked page (About single word requests) for more information.

Comment: The image is so clear that there is no need of further information, -1.

Comment: @Elberich The image does not tell us how it will be used.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: The image is not at all clear.  We can't read what is on the papers.  And we can't tell whether the people are motionless and silent, yelling, making angels on the concrete, etc.

Comment: @Ben Voigt That people is a group of people who lie down in a public place in order to send a political message.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: And it is good that you added that clarifying text to your question.